# Temporarily redirect child process stdout on Linux and Windows

Tags: winapi, redirect, process, posix, pipe

I have to write a process launcher which starts another process and reads its standard error up to a certain status flag but exits afterwards. The application that is started must keep running. I can succesfully redirect stderr to a pipe and read it from the launcher. My concern is what happens after the launcher terminates. The read end of the pipe is then closed and the application tries writing to a broken pipe. How does one undo the redirection after the child process is started?

What makes the problem even more challenging is that the launcher is cross platform and must be implemented in both POSIX and WinAPI.

Any suggestions on any of the platforms is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case the parent process (the launcher) exits you will end up (1) with an orphan process and (2) with a broken pipe for stderr. Both these things sound bad...

Some ideas:

1. Redirect the stderr to a file (i imagine you would want to keep all error messages anyway). The parent/launcher/or any other monitoring process can read from the file as much as needed, at any time, and without getting I/O errors.
2. Detach the program from the launcher. Usually this is done using fork() followed by an execve() in the forked child process.